# jquery tooltip mouseout mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Problem. The following Tooltip working great, but there is a Problem. When i go with the mouse to the right side, the cursor is faster then the tooltip and will hover it. This will hide and show the Cursor for a split Second.

```
http://gabibyte.zxq.net/jquery_tooltips/example.html
// !REMEMBER TO INCLUDE JQUERY IN YOUR PAGE - IF YOU DON'T KNOW HOW, JUST INCLUDE THE LINE OF CODE BELOW IN THE <HEAD>...</HEAD> PART OF YOUR PAGE
/* <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script> */
//----------------------------------------------CONFIGURATION
var offset=15; //Distance between tooltip and cursor
var fadeInSpeed=600; //Speed of the Fade-IN effect in miliseconds
var fadeOutSpeed=200; //Speed of the Fade-OUT effect in miliseconds
var clearQueue = true; //If set to false, if you hover over many elements fast, the events will stack up
var gotoEnd= true; //If set to false, if you hover over many elements fast, the events will stack up
//---------------------------------------------GLOBAL VARIABLES
var mouseX,mouseY; 
$(document).ready(function(){
//-----------------------------------------------MOUSE EVENTS
  $(document).mousemove(function(e){
     mouseX=e.pageX+offset;
     mouseY=e.pageY;+offset
     $('.floating').css('top',mouseY);
     $('.floating').css('left',mouseX);
  });
//------------------------------------------------HOVER EVENTS
$('.hastooltip').hover(function () {
    var selector ="#"+ $(this).attr('tooltip');
    //alert(selector);
    //$(selector).stop(clearQueue , gotoEnd) 
    $(selector).fadeIn(250,function () {});
},function () {
    var selector ="#"+ $(this).attr('tooltip');
    $(selector).fadeOut(fadeOutSpeed,function () {});

    }
);
});
```

Is there any way to say for onmouseout "if hover toolbox do nothing else fadeOut".

Comment: Can you explain your problem a bit more please? I don't understand what you're trying to fix.

Answer (score 0):

use     `.mouseout()`

http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Comment: I have mouseout

[code]var selector ="#"+ $(this).attr('tooltip');
    $(selector).fadeOut(fadeOutSpeed,function () {});[/code]

Comment: I have mouseout

var selector ="#"+ $(this).attr('tooltip');
    $(selector).fadeOut(fadeOutSpeed,function () {});

I'm searching a way to to stop the FadeOut, when the Tooltip is hovered.
Like if(selector).is('hover') ... else ... fade out

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.setTimeout()` for the stuff you want to happen on the hover off. Then have a hover for your tooltip that cancels that timeout (using `.clearTimeout()`). You'll probably want the same setTimeout/clearTimeout on the element and the tooltip hover offs/ons (respectively), so that if someone returns their mouse to either of them, the hover off doesn't happen.

So if you have a 2-second timeout, the timer will start when someone hovers off, but as long as someone hovers from the element to the tooltip within 2 seconds it'll get cancelled.

Comment: this is a great idea, i will try it. Is there a way to set this event automatic like ?

$(selector).hover(function(){ $(this).clearTimeout })

Comment: You could store it in the element. `$(this).data('timer', setTimeout( ... ));` And then: `clearTimeout( $(this).data('timer') );`  But then in your tooltip you'd have to be able to find that element to be able to cancel its timeout. If your tooltip is inside the element then it'd be easy ( `clearTimeout( $(this).parent().data('timer') );` ).